# Add to cart functionality - Core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to create the best possible design for the following scenario.

Category -> The list of products

In the tableview where the list of products is shown, the user has the option to add that product to the cart.
So, whenever the user opens the cart, he can see all of the products he has added.

My question is how can I best setup this functionality in Core Data? Is the best solution to maintain a separate Cart Entity? Or is a relationship the right way to do it?, If yes can you please tell me what kind a relationship it should be between Cart & Product?

Comment: Make a Cart entity as you suggested with a to-many relationship with a CartProduct entity.  Cart entity can contain 'meta' information about the purchase and CartProduct would link to the actual Product entity.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for your quick answer. I just have a question: what kind of link/relationship should I create between Product entity and the CartProduct entity?.. Thank you for the help again, it's appreciated :).

Comment: Added answer to clarify.

Comment: can i do it using plist ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `Cart` entity as you suggested with a ***To-Many*** relationship with a `CartProduct` entity. `Cart` entity can contain 'meta' information about the purchase and `CartProduct` would link to the actual `Product` entity.

The type of relationship between a `CartProduct` entity and `Product` entity would essentially be a 1-1, so in Xcode, in the data model editor, with the `CartProduct` entity selected, be sure to add the `Product` entity as a relationship in the ***Relationships*** section and leave the ***To-Many Relationship*** setting unchecked.  The values would be something like this:

- Relationship: Product
- Destination: Product
- Inverse: CartProduct

Then, select the `Product` entity in the editor and double check that a relationship exists that looks something like this (again, make sure that the ***To-Many Relationship*** setting is unchecked):

- Relationship: CartProduct
- Destination: CartProduct
- Inverse: Product

The above should get you started.

Comment: I hope it's okay for me to post further questions about this, here, if I become in "trouble" :).

Comment: Sure thing.  There is a large SO community always willing to help.  Be sure to create a new question for each new question you may have.

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you. I have a small question related to your answer above. Should I make the relations between all these entitys (code, addProductObject etc) when the user pushes the "add to cart" button, or before? Thank you :).

Comment: I would do it when they hit the button since that's probably the only way to determine if user is initiating a purchase, albeit, the beginning stages of a purchase.