# Fetch relationships and show in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have the following relationship set up in my Core Data model, in my shopping cart app.

`Menu` ->> `Product` <<- `Cart` (See picture below).

[image]

And a Objective-C category with the following code:

```
+ (Cart *)addProductToCartWithProduct:(Product *)product inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Cart *cart = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cart" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSManagedObjectID *retID = [product objectID];
    [(Product *)[context objectWithID:retID] setInCart:cart];
    [cart addProductsObject:(Product *)[context objectWithID:retID]];    

    return cart;
}
```

When the user pushes the "add to cart" button in the app, this method is fired (the method above). I now want to fetch these products (which is added to the cart by the user), in my other class, where the "cart" is located. I want these products to be shown in my `UITableView` in that class, I therefore use an FRC. *But I can't figure out how to fetch the relationship and thereby show the products. How would I manage to do this?*

I have the following code right now.

```
- (void)loadCart
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cart" inManagedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"cartproducts"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"cartproducts"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch Failed");        
    }
}
```

My `UITableview` `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *plainCellIdentifier = @"OrderCell";

    ProductsCell *cell = (ProductsCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:plainCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ProductsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:plainCellIdentifier];
    }

    Cart *ret = (Cart *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // How to show the product names using the relationship? 
    cell.title = ret.products ??;  

    [cell setNeedsDisplay];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: So you want to display the products for one specific cart?

Comment: Yes, I only have one cart in my app. Is this possible? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display product for one specific cart, you would create the fetched results controller
as follows *(not compiler checked, there may be syntax errors!)* :

```
Cart *theCart = ... the cart that you want display products for ...

// Fetch request for "Product":
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];

// Fetch only products for the cart:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inCart = %@", theCart];
[fetchRequest setPredicate] = predicate;

// Assuming that you want to sort by "navn":
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"navn" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

The fetched objects are now `Product` objects, therefore in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would do for example:

```
...
Product *product = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.title = product.navn;
```

*Remark:* The fetched results controller uses a cache (as far as I know) only for section information, so there is no need to specify a `cacheName:` here.

Comment: Thank you very much :). I think I misunderstod your comment to the question above. I do not have a specific cart I want to fetch from, just all the product objects which is added to the relationship, does this change anything to the approach? Thank you :).

Comment: @Seya: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want exactly. My code shows all products related to one specific cart object. How is that different from "all the product objects which is added to the relationship"? - And note also that (as correctly said in the other answer) your addProductToCartWithProduct creates a new Cart object each time that you call it, which is perhaps not what you want.

Comment: @Seya: In other words, the code in my answer can be used to display  `theCart.products` in a table view. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @MartinR: Sorry, it's just me, you are correct. I was just confused about, where to get the cart object, which is used in the predicate. I have found out. I just need to pass the instance of the Cart object which is returned from my method :). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your new model is good.

Now that I understand your approach better, I think you do need to do a fetch kind of like your original code. I mistakenly assumed you'd want to have more than one cart - I'm thinking like a server engineer I guess.

```
+ (Cart *)addProductToCart:(Product *)theProduct inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    Cart *cart = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Cart"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *carts = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!carts || ([carts count] > 1)) {
        // handle error
    } else if (![carts count]) {
        cart = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cart" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    } else { // they already have a cart started
        cart = [carts lastObject];
    }
    [cart addProductsObject:theProduct];

    return cart;
}
```

You don't need this: `NSManagedObjectID *retID = [product objectID];`. Just refer to the product by the Product object. You don't need to round-trip it by its ID in this case.

You don't need this: `[(Product *)[context objectWithID:retID] setInCart:cart];`. With the inverses properly configured, adding theProduct to the cart automatically sets theProduct.inCart.

The other answer is good for how to do the fetched results controller.

Comment: Hey, without adding an attribute to the product entity, how can I model the count of a given product in the cart? Suppose the cart needs to have 3 A's, 2 B's where A and B are products.